# How to get inclusive total hours using TimeSpan in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I'm using TimeSpan function in VB.NET to get the total hours in a billing month.

I have 30 days in a billing month, so supposedly, I have 720 intervals. Using Timespan normally, I would get 696 intervals. But I add a day in my "todate" in order to get my correct total hours.
This is my code:

```
Dim TS As TimeSpan   
Dim totalhours As Integer
Dim todate As DateTime = #11-30-2014#
Dim fromdate As DateTime = #11-01-2014#

TS = todate.AddDays(1).Subtract(fromdate)
totalhours = TS.TotalHours
```

However, I don't think that manipulating my input date (by adding a day) is the best practice. Is there any way to configure the timespan function to get the inclusive total hours?

Comment: You are needing to add the day because you are essentially performing the integer subtraction `30 - 1 = 29`. Your date times are starting at midnight of each day so you are ignoring the 24 hours that are part of the last day.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you did not supply the time range. The date alone will be 12AM for the time part.

```
Dim TS As TimeSpan   
Dim totalhours As Integer
Dim todate As DateTime = #11-30-2014 11:59:59 PM#
Dim fromdate As DateTime = #11-01-2014#

TS = todate.Subtract(fromdate)
totalhours = TS.TotalHours
```

That will be 1 hours shy.

```
Dim TS As TimeSpan   
Dim totalhours As Integer
Dim todate As DateTime = #12-01-2014#
Dim fromdate As DateTime = #11-01-2014#

TS = todate.Subtract(fromdate)
totalhours = TS.TotalHours
```

Will get the correct amount since it is inclusive of time between the two dates.

Comment: or just cast your result to an Integer `totalhours = CInt(TS.TotalHours)`